# what are protocols used during accessing email via web browsers?

Tags: email

All I know is smpt, pop3 and imap are  used for email transactions . But when I access my email (gmail or hotmail) via web browsers , we use http or https. (whereas Smpt is used in email client like outlook, thunder bird,etc..)

can anyone tell me how this is working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/HTTPS is for presentation.

Email is still using SMTP for sending mail, and either POP3 or IMAP for receiving/fetching from the email server.  Whatever language in between -- PHP, Java, .NET, etc -- has libraries to handle the information appropriately.